# Amazon CloudWatch - monitoring EBS volumes VolumeReadOps, VolumeWriteOps

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs, amazon-cloudwatch

I am interesting in adding CloudWatch for two specific stats on just a few named EBS volumes. The metrics specifically are VolumeReadOps and VolumeWriteOps. These do not show up by default under the volume graphs. My question is as follows:

- Is it possible to have those graphs show up by default underneath all volumes graphs tab?
- Is it possible to search volumes by tag/name when going to CloudWatch -> EBS? Do I really have to remember volumes by volume-id if I want to see some metrics?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add a custom metrics to cloud watch. But you can still monitor the VolumeReadIops and VolumeWriteIops using munin. I will give many other information like your app server performance, web server performance etc etc.